# When adding new content types in Drupal, do they need to be added in the DEV environment first?

Tags: drupal, development-environment, production-environment, acquia

I am wanting to add a new content type to a Drupal site. We have hosting through Acquia with Dev, Staging, and Prod environments.

I am new to having multiple hosting environments. As I understand it, new content can be added at Prod and code changes need to be implemented on Dev.

Do new content types need to be added to Dev first and moved up or can they safely be added to Prod and still avoid being over written in the next sprint?